# Get Contents of form Element with Same Name in Jquery. Accessing Childeren of the Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with the format

```
<form>
<fieldset>
  <label for="select_label">Enter Label </label>
  <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="select_label" name="select_label" gtbfieldid="307">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <label for="select_option">Option</label>
  <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" name="select_option" gtbfieldid="308">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <label for="select_option">Option</label>
  <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="1" name="select_option">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <label for="select_option">Option</label>
  <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="2" name="select_option">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <label for="select_option">Option</label>
  <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="3" name="select_option">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <label for="select_option">Option</label>
  <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="4" name="select_option">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Add More Option" id="add_more" name="add_more">
</fieldset>
```

and i am trying to get the values of all the inputs whose name is "select_option".
I have a java script code which loops for the number of times the element occurs but i can`t get the Value of those

```
for(var i=0 ; i<$('input[name=select_option]').size(); i++)
{
    alert(i);
    alert($('input[name=select_option]').children(i));
            //alert($('input[name=select_option]').children()[0].find("input").val());
}
```

You can see the above code and what i have commented out does not work for me. any idea?

Comment: The `for` attribute on `<label>` elements references a (unique) **id**, not a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$('input[name=select_option]').each(function(){alert($(this).val())});
```

Comment: Infact 
    $('input[name=select_option]').each(function(){alert($(this).val())}); this worked

Answer (score 3):

You do not mean `.children(i)`. You mean `.get(i)`, or even better just `[i]`:

```
for(var i=0 ; i<$('input[name=select_option]').size(); i++) {
    alert(i);
    // both .get() and array index return a DOM object
    alert($('input[name=select_option]').get(i).value);
    alert($('input[name=select_option]')[i].value); 
    // or, if you want to use .val(), wrap it in jQuery again
    alert( $($('input[name=select_option]')[i]).val() ); 
}
```

But that's not very nice or efficient. At least you could save the result of `$('input[name=select_option]')` to a variable before entering the loop. However, jQuery makes iterating easy, so use `.each()`:

```
var values = [];
$('input[name=select_option]').each( function () {
  values.push(this.value);
});
```

or maybe even

```
var values = $('input[name=select_option]').map( function () {
  return this.value;
});
```

Note that `$.map()` - being a normal jQuery function - returns a jQuery object. For many intents these objects behave exactly like arrays.

If you need to get a *real* array, though, use [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
var values = $('input[name=select_option]').map( function () {
  return this.value;
}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Input` elements don't have children.

```
$('input[name="select_option"]').each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + " " $(this).val());
});
```

This snippet will iterate over `input` elements whose attribute `name` is equal to `select_option` and log their value.

Answer (score 0):

The object doesn't have any children. An element is a child of the element it is (directly) inside.

You probably want something like:

```
$('input[name=select_option]').each(someFunction);
```

See the [documentation for each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

```
        alert('Quick answer...')
        // quick fix is to use `.eq()` instead of `.children()`
        for(var i=0 ; i<$('input[name=select_option]').size(); i++)
        {
            alert(i);
            alert($('input[name=select_option]').eq(i).val());
        }

        alert('Better answer...')
        // Better way            
        $('input[name=select_option]').each(function(k,v){
            alert(k);
            alert($(v).val())
        })
```